# How to compare points in homogeneous coordinates universally?

Tags: projective-geometry, computational-geometry, computer-vision

## Problem

Given a plane, I have lines in the canonical form (described by 3D vectors). Using a cross product, I can find an intersection of any two lines. I want to check, whether two pairs of lines intersect at the same point, taking noisiness of the data into account. This means that I should compare them with respect to a chosen threshold

$$
p_1 = \ell_1 \times \ell_2 \\
p_2 = \ell_3 \times \ell_4 \\
\left( l_1 \nparallel l_2 \right) \land \left( l_3 \nparallel l_4 \right) \implies
\left( p_1^z \neq 0 \right) \land \left( p_2^z \neq 0 \right) \implies
\left\lVert \frac{p_1}{p_1^z} - \frac{p_2}{p_2^z} \right\rVert < \varepsilon?
$$

If two given lines are **not** parallel, their intersection point has a non-zero third coordinate. So, I can divide by it to get ordinary 2D coordinates of the point and compare it with another one in the usual way.
Otherwise, if the lines **are** parallel, the third coordinate of their intersection point is close to zero (meaning it's the point at infinity), so I cannot divide by it and should compare the directions of two points at infinity

$$
p_1 = \ell_1 \times \ell_2 \\
p_2 = \ell_3 \times \ell_4 \\
\left( l_1 \parallel l_2 \right) \land \left( l_3 \parallel l_4 \right) \implies
\left( p_1^z \approx 0 \approx p_2^z \right) \implies
\left\lVert
\frac{p_1}{\left\lVert p_1 \right\rVert} - \frac{p_2}{\left\lVert p_2 \right\rVert}
\right\rVert < \varepsilon?
$$

## Question

Is there a universal way to compare points in a homogeneous coordinate system to avoid the separate check of the third coordinate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can "normalize" as you've done: replace $p_1$ by $q_1 = \frac{p_1}{\|p_1\|}$, and similarly for $p_2$ to get a pair of unit vectors in the 2-sphere in 3-space. There's a small problem here, which is that even if $p_1$ and $p_2$ represent the same point, $q_1$ and $q_2$ might point in opposite directions (i.e., $p_1 = -q_2$).

So the next step is to compute $d = q_1 \cdot q_2$, and if $d < 0$, you negate $q_2$. (I'm going to assume you've done this, and now call the replaced vector $q_2$.)

Now you've got two vectors in the same hemisphere of $S^2$, so to measure how far apart they are, you can compute the angle between them:
$$
\theta = \arccos(q_1 \cdot q_2).
$$

(Noting that $\cos$ is an even function, you'll realize that the whole "negate $q_2$ isn't actually necessary...)

This value $\theta$ gives you a "distance" between the computed intersections.

Is $\theta$ invariant with respect to the various transformations that matter to you? You might, for instance, say "If I changed coordinates by translating everything by $(a,b)$ for any part of numbers $(a,b)$, then the 'distance' should be unchanged". If you want that, then you have to check whether $\theta$ has that property. Since I don't know what properties you wish to have, I can't really go any farther.

Comment: Counterexample. Suppose we have two vectors $p_1 = \left\langle 10^6, 10^6, 1 \right\rangle$ and $p_2 = \left\langle 10^6, 10^6, 0 \right\rangle$. Then $q_1 \approx \left\langle \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \cdot 10^{-6} \right\rangle$ and $q_2 \approx \left\langle \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, 0 \right\rangle$. Their dot product is $q_1 \cdot q_2 \approx 1$, thus  $\arccos{\left( q_1 \cdot q_2 \approx 1 \right)} \approx 0$. Though, the point $p_1$ is at a specific point whereas $p_2$ is at the infinity, so they are not the same point.

Comment: Ah ... so one of your constraints is that the "distance" between finite points be approximately the Euclidean distance. Let's look at lines $x = 1$ and $x = -1$, with equations $1x + 0y - 1 = 0$ and $1x + 0y +1 = 0$. Given that everything in your world is apparently subject to numerical error, these are pretty much the same as $1x \mp ay \pm 1$ where $a \approx 0$. If we pick $a = .001$, then the intersection point occurs at $(0, 1000)$; if we pick $a = -.001$, the intersection occurs at $(0, -1000)$. Since the lines (and line-pairs) are evidently "close" (by making $a$ smaller as needed), ...

Comment: ...you have to decide  whether to call these two intersection points "close" or not. They're certainly not "Euclidean close". I suspect that if you try to write down your problem really carefully, you'll discover that there's no consistent answer. Since you're interested in numerical computations, you might want to specify the problem with specific and well-defined error bounds. (Any numerical approach that involves testing floating-point equality is pretty much doomed to failure, for instance.)

Comment: Let me try to condense my answer: "Given noise in the data, there's no reliable way to tell whether the intersection point occurs at a finite or infinite point for near-parallel lines." So branching-on-parallelism is sure to produce inconsistent results.

Comment: I see, thanks! Yes, I didn't get that the error in dot product is squared, so instead of, say, `10^{-6}` I get something like `10^{-12}` and this confused me a lot